# Java 11 Upgrade - Springboot app - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/TextEncryptor

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, java-8, java-11

We have existing web application using springboot '`2.3.4.RELEASE`',    `Tomcat 9,` `Java 8`

App is working fine from months in Java 8. Just today we upgraded JRE to 11, and re used same old war that was already deployed in tomcat, and started tomcat.

Now we have **upgraded to JRE 11,** and app fails to start.

In `pom.xml`, we have excluded `spring-security` as we do not require, i can add basis on below exception and it might work. But need to understand what changed from Java 8 to Java 11, which actually requires spring-security class.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/TextEncryptor
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
                at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.hasNoConstructors(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:291)
                at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.isEligible(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:283)
                at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:156)
                at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:136)
                at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:128)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:691)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
                at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
                at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:208)
                at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104)
                at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70)
                at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
                at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
                at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
                at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 38 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion></modelVersion>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>19</version>
    <name></name>
    <url></url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <org.powermock-version>2.0.7</org.powermock-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>servlets.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>cos</artifactId>
            <version>05Nov2002</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Dependencies start -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-uml</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Dependencies End -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>


        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    
        <!-- Junit -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${org.powermock-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${org.powermock-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent</artifactId>
            <version>${org.powermock-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you please include more context of your setup, perhaps with a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Upgrading the JDK alone does not introduce a dependency on Spring Security classes, so there must be something additional to look at. I'd encourage you to try [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) and experiment with various versions of Spring Boot, and upgrade to an [OSS supported version](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) such as 2.5.x.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I respect your point, but i rollback jdk back to version 8, and everything seems to be fine. Just FYI, this app is running in production from months now, no additional code changes done. just Java version was upgraded and rollback later. Even war is still same that we compiled with Java 8, we change JRE 11, and switched back to JRE 8

Comment: I totally understand. I'm asking for additional context because there's something in the application setup that is going to be different in JDK 11, and I don't know what that would be without some hints as to your setup. Providing a pom.xml for example would be helpful. It's likely a transitive runtime dependency if you're explicitly excluding spring security.

Comment: If you visit the release notes, a lot of things have changed from Java-8 to Java-11, one of the related aspects could be classloading. Upgraded versions of the library would have ensured that these issues are fixed, so the path would not be that straightforward to upgrade it in production. You would have to take one step at a time.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I have added pom.xml, this same owkr with java 8 in tomcat 9, but as soon as i point to java 11, tomcat fails to start, throwing above error.

Comment: @Naman i understand your point, but i am still not abel to understand what changed in Java 11 that it is trying to invoke spring security lib, as my app does not need this at all.

Comment: I would strongly suspect the error is coming from your spring-cloud-config-client dependency. Various components of spring cloud config and commons depend on spring-security-crypto. As @Naman suggested, it's possible there's a class loader change that's triggering different behavior, causing an error. The error seems likely due to the exclusions in your pom. Try removing the exclusions to spring-cloud-config-client and re-deploy to see if the error goes away, to narrow it down. Depending on spring-security-crypto should be ok, so I recommend removing the exclusion anyway.